# How to loop over pointers to structs

Tags: c, pointers, memory-management, struct

I have a for loop that looks like so:

```
for (i2 = 0; i2 < n_lines; i2++) {
    statfs_full *f_tmp;
    f_tmp = malloc(sizeof(statfs_full));
    struct statfs *tmp;
    tmp = malloc(sizeof(statfs));

    statfs(fse[i2].fs_file, tmp);

    merge_statfs_structs(tmp, &f_tmp);
    strcpy(f_tmp->f_fstypename, fse[i2].fs_vsftype);
    strcpy(f_tmp->f_mntonname, fse[i2].fs_file);
    strcpy(f_tmp->f_mntfromname, fse[i2].fs_spec);

    free(f_tmp); 
    free(tmp);
```

It is part of a much larger function. `statfs_full` is a typdef'ed struct that is just a standard `struct statfs` with three fields added. The call to function `merge_statfs_structs()` populates my expanded struct pointed to by f_tmp with the values from the standard struct pointed to by `tmp`. The three calls to `strcpy()` populate the extra three fields.

The code compiles OK, but I can see from some printf calls that the program is segfaulting at the call(s) to `free()`. Earlier I had the declarations and malloc calls outside the loop, and tried resetting both structs to NULL, but that is segfaulting on the second call to `merge_statfs_structs`.

So I guess my question is how does one 'reset' the structs pointed to by f_tmp and tmp for each time through the loop?

Edit: Adding source of `merge_statfs_structs` in case it is germane...

```
int merge_statfs_structs(struct statfs *buf, statfs_full **buf_full) {
    int i;
    (*buf_full)->f_type    = buf->f_type;
    (*buf_full)->f_bsize   = buf->f_bsize;
    (*buf_full)->f_blocks  = buf->f_blocks;
    (*buf_full)->f_bfree   = buf->f_bfree;
    (*buf_full)->f_bavail  = buf->f_bavail;
    (*buf_full)->f_files   = buf->f_files;
    (*buf_full)->f_ffree   = buf->f_ffree;
    (*buf_full)->f_fsid    = buf->f_fsid;
    (*buf_full)->f_namelen = buf->f_namelen;
    (*buf_full)->f_frsize  = buf->f_frsize;

    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        (*buf_full)->f_spare[i]   = buf->f_spare[i];
    return 0;
}
```

Edit 2: adding definition of `mounted_fs_entry` and `struct statfs_full`:

```
#define FS_TYPE_LEN      90
#define MNT_FLAGS_LEN    256

typedef struct _mounted_fs_entry {
    char fs_spec[PATH_MAX];           /* device or special file system path */
    char fs_file[PATH_MAX];           /* mount point */
    char fs_vsftype[FS_TYPE_LEN];     /* file system type */
    char fs_mntops[MNT_FLAGS_LEN];    /* mount flags */
    int  fs_freq;                     /* dump */
    int  fs_passno;                   /* pass */
} mounted_fs_entry;

#if __WORDSIZE == 32
#define __WORD_TYPE int
#else /* __WORDSIZE == 64 */
#define __WORD_TYPE long int
#endif

typedef struct _statfs_full {
    __WORD_TYPE  f_type;             /* type of filesystem */
    __WORD_TYPE  f_bsize;            /* optimal transfer block size */
    fsblkcnt_t   f_blocks;           /* total data blocks in filesystem */
    fsblkcnt_t   f_bfree;            /* free blocks in fs */
    fsblkcnt_t   f_bavail;           /* free blocks available to unprivileged user */
    fsfilcnt_t   f_files;            /* total file nodes in filesystem */
    fsfilcnt_t   f_ffree;            /* free file nodes in fs */
    fsid_t       f_fsid;             /* filesystem id */
    __WORD_TYPE  f_namelen;          /* maximum length of filenames */
    __WORD_TYPE  f_frsize;           /* fragment size (since Linux 2.6) */
    __WORD_TYPE  f_spare[5];

    /* these extra fields add path info as in the *BSD versions of statfs() */
    char f_fstypename[FS_TYPE_LEN];  /* fs type name */
    char f_mntonname[PATH_MAX];      /* directory on which mounted */
    char f_mntfromname[PATH_MAX];    /* mounted file sytem */
} statfs_full;
```

I did not define `struct stafs` myself, it is defined in `/usr/include/sys/statfs.h`, or you can just `man statfs`. `mounted_fs_entry` is the struct referenced by `fse[i2]` in the for loop. I have the entire file on github [here](https://github.com/DarrenKirby/dgnu-utils/blob/master/src/mount.h) if you want to have a look.

I have been playing with this a bit more in gdb, the segfault is happening inside glibc, during the call to free. Unfortunately my glibc is not built with debugging symbols, so I can't use valgrind to track it down.

Comment: probably you're writing out of bound in the new fields, `strcpy` copy until `\0` is found. Are you sure the origin field end with `\0`? some times have fixed size like `char field[16];`.

Comment: No, I double checked, even changed `strcpy` to `strncpy` and matched the source/destination sizes exactly. I am able to print the values fine. Ran it through gdb 'backtrace' and got this:

`1  0x0000000000401303 in getfsstat_linux (buf=0x7fffffffdf90, bufsize=453452) at src/mount.h:165`

Line 165 is the first call to free().

Comment: You might like to show how `struct statfs_full` and `struct statfs` are defined.

Comment: Please compile with all warnings and debug info (`gcc -Wall -g`) and **use the debugger** (`gdb`)

Comment: Thanks Basile, I have been doing so. As I say, the segfault is occurring inside glibc during the `free()` call. Not sure how to debug further as my glibc was not built with debug symbols. Now: before I go through the trouble of rebuilding glibc, I would very much appreciate some opinions on how I've implemented the loop in my first code post. Is malloc/free a reasonable way to reset temporary structs for each trip through the loop? If not I'd rather rewrite that bit than debug bad code that will need to be changed anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out myself. Moved the malloc/free calls outside the loop, and got rid of the typedef statements while defining the structs. Works good now. Here's the updated code (without the error checking removed):

```
struct statfs_ext *sas = malloc(sizeof(struct statfs_ext) * n_lines);

struct statfs_ext *f_tmp;
f_tmp = malloc(sizeof(struct statfs_ext));
if (f_tmp == NULL) {
    perror("unable to malloc");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

struct statfs *s_tmp;
s_tmp = malloc(sizeof(struct statfs));
if (s_tmp == NULL) {
    perror("unable to malloc");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

for (i2 = 0; i2 < n_lines; i2++) {

    if (statfs(fse[i2].fs_file, s_tmp) != 0) {
        perror("statfs() failed");
        continue; /* might not be fatal */
    }
    merge_statfs_structs(s_tmp, &f_tmp);

    strncpy(f_tmp->f_fstypename, fse[i2].fs_vsftype, FS_TYPE_LEN);      
    strncpy(f_tmp->f_mntonname, fse[i2].fs_file, PATH_MAX);
    strncpy(f_tmp->f_mntfromname, fse[i2].fs_spec, PATH_MAX);

    sas[i2] = *f_tmp;

}

free(s_tmp);
free(f_tmp);
```

And the stuct definitions:

```
#define FS_TYPE_LEN      90
#define MNT_FLAGS_LEN    256

struct mounted_fs_entry {
    char fs_spec[PATH_MAX];           /* device or special file system path */
    char fs_file[PATH_MAX];           /* mount point */
    char fs_vsftype[FS_TYPE_LEN];     /* file system type */
    char fs_mntops[MNT_FLAGS_LEN];    /* mount flags */
    int  fs_freq;                     /* dump */
    int  fs_passno;                   /* pass */
};

#if __WORDSIZE == 32
#define __WORD_TYPE int
#else /* __WORDSIZE == 64 */
#define __WORD_TYPE long int
#endif

struct statfs_ext {
    __WORD_TYPE  f_type;             /* type of filesystem (see below) */
    __WORD_TYPE  f_bsize;            /* optimal transfer block size */
    fsblkcnt_t   f_blocks;           /* total data blocks in filesystem */
    fsblkcnt_t   f_bfree;            /* free blocks in fs */
    fsblkcnt_t   f_bavail;           /* free blocks available to unprivileged user */
    fsfilcnt_t   f_files;            /* total file nodes in filesystem */
    fsfilcnt_t   f_ffree;            /* free file nodes in fs */
    fsid_t       f_fsid;             /* filesystem id */
    __WORD_TYPE  f_namelen;          /* maximum length of filenames */
    __WORD_TYPE  f_frsize;           /* fragment size (since Linux 2.6) */
    __WORD_TYPE  f_spare[5];

    /* these extra fields add path info as in the *BSD versions of statfs() */
    char f_fstypename[FS_TYPE_LEN];  /* fs type name */
    char f_mntonname[PATH_MAX];      /* directory on which mounted */
    char f_mntfromname[PATH_MAX];    /* mounted file sytem */
};
```